# How to modify xml list item property via powershell

Tags: list-item, property

---

Hi all,

i have a sharepoint 2010 site with blog, blog contains few posts with comments.
I need to modify comment property via powershel.

Have used the following code:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://portal/strategy  \\get the site
$dd = $spWeb.Lists["Comments"]  \\get the list of all comments
$dd.Items[1] \\ here i select required comment
```

Now i can see it's properties like

Xml:

```
<z:row xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' ows_ID='19' ows_ContentTypeId='0x0111008F1E084351F                                         D240821BA37C4537E336' ows_ContentType='Comment'  ows_Title='test' ows_Modified=
'2012-09-28 14:42:25' ows_Created='2012-09-28 14:29:53' ows_Author='1;#spsadmin' ... />
```

So the problem is so i can't modify that ows property, like ows_Created or ows_Modified via powershell.

Thanks.

Comment: Why must you use XML, why not `$dd.GetItemById(1)["Created"] = Date`

Comment: Because PS returns error which i couldn't understand:                   `PS C:\Users\spsadmin> $dd.GetItemById(19)["Created"] = 2012-09-27
**Unable to index into an object of type** Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.
At line:1 char:21
+ $dd.GetItemById(19)[ <<<< "Created"] = 2012-09-27
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Created:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex`

Comment: looks like the required item doesn't have this property, because all similar are included into Xml which is shown above.

Comment: Try using `Date` as I did in my example, does it work?

Comment: sad but not working

Comment: 1 - As far as I know, the created and modified are read only fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as I know, Created and Modified fields are read only fields on SharePoint, so even if you're accessing in the right way, you wont be able to update their values.
2. By all means, avoid using `web.Lists["ListName"].` Instead use `web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName")`. Your app/script performance will improve

Answer (score 0):

All of the ows_ prefixes are added to the XML due to backwards compatablity with the xml used when SharePoint as called "Office Web Server", but are not part of the field names.

You can update the comment with powershell like this:

```
$i = $dd.GetItemById(19)
$i["Created"] = Get-Date "2012-09-27"
$i.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change system properties like `Created`, `Created By`, `Modified` and `Modified By` as well:

```
$dd = $spWeb.Lists["Comments"]
$item = $dd.Items[1] 
$item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Author] = "1;#Edward Wilde"
$item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Editor] = "1;#Edward Wilde"
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

See these references:

https://blogs.edwardwilde.com/2010/04/21/how-do-you-update-the-author-or-created-by-and-editor-or-modified-by-last-modified-fields-of-a-list-item-splistitem/

https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/changing-system-properties-for-an-item-from-the-sharepoint-user-interface-part-1/